# Privacy Policy URL - What if I use it for the owner's website only?

Tags: instagram

So, apparently I need to provide a Privacy Policy URL for my Instagram application.

The only reason I'm using this application, is for a website I built for a client of mine. The client wanted an automatic integration for her Instagram, so I went through the whole Instagram API hassle.

Now, the website is ready for production, so I wanted to get my app out of sandbox mode, but it looks like I need this Privacy Policy URL.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Put a Privacy Policy page up on their website (really any website you can link to) and use that link. It can be a static HTML page, as long as you can link to it.

Instagram won't let you take an application like this out of Sandbox, btw. Your use case is not an approved use case. From Instagram's Developer Documentation under [Invalid Use Cases](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/):

> **One-off Projects**. If you are an agency building websites or other integrations, note that we don't grant permissions to clients created for one-off projects. If you are interested in building a product, platform, or widget that will be used as a service across multiple projects, then you may submit a single client_id that you can use across multiple projects.

You can (probably) still achieve the outcome you're looking for but you will need to go back to the drawing board and rethink your application's use case before getting out of the Sandbox. I know some developers who really just don't understand (or care to understand) the policies and never make it out of Sandbox. It's a shame because they can read the technical portions of the documentation so easily but just can't/don't read/understand the more critical parts (like the Invalid Use Cases section).